# Message collecter spams messages, and wont start in the correct channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, I have been making a message collector that gets activated when "grimm!record" is sent, I have been working on this piece of code for hours, but yet the code seems to keep getting more broken.
This was the code before I started working on it

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'grimm!record') {
        const filter = m => true;
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter);
        message.channel.send(Start)
        const log = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'recording-log');
        collector.on('collect', collectedMessage=>{
        log.send(`${message.author.username} - ${collectedMessage.content}`)    
    if(collectedMessage.content === "grimm!record-stop"){
        collector.stop();

    }
});
    }})
```

and this is the code after I made edits, If grimm!record was sent in the channel called recording-log, the bot would send a message saying "I can't record the recording log!" and it would exit out of the collector

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'grimm!record') {
        const channelID = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "recording-log").id;
        if (message.channel.id === channelID)
        message.channel.send('I cant record in the Recording Log!') 
        return;
} else {
        message.channel.send(Start)
        const filter = m => true;
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter);
        const log = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'recording-log');
        collector.on('collect', collectedMessage=>{
        log.send(`${message.author.username} - ${collectedMessage.content}`)
    if(collectedMessage.content === "grimm!record-stop"){
        collector.stop();

    }
});
    }})
```

Once I made these edits, I would send grimm!record in a different channel, it does not start the collector, or even send the "Start" embed, and the collector does start as well, when I sent grimm!record in the recording-log, I got a message saying that the bot cant record the recording log, but it still starts the collector, while spamming the "Start" embed in the channel. I have been working on this for hours, I've been looking all over the internet for help, but yet I still have no clue on what I've been doing wrong, could someone tell me what's wrong with the 2nd piece of code I sent? Thanks!

EDIT - so it turns out, that anytime I use a command with my bot, or if someone says a word that is in my bots swear list, it starts the collector, and starts the message spam, so I have no clue on why that happens, so if someone could help explain that, I would appreciate that too, thanks!

Comment: `const filter = m => true;` This is probably a significant factor in the problem you are having. There is a purpose to the filter, it should not simply return true. The filter is responsible for "filtering" out the messages you do not want collected. Only messages that match the conditions of the filter will be collected. In your example, there is no filter, so *any* message sent by *anyone* will be collected by the collector, including messages sent by the bot itself. Since your bot sends a new message whenever a message is collected, this results in an infinite loop of spam.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line should theoretically solve your issue:

```
const filter = m => true;
```

As I stated in my comment, there is a purpose to the filter, it should not simply return true. The filter is responsible for "filtering" out the messages you do not want collected. Only messages that match the conditions of the filter will be collected. In your example, there is no filter, so *any* message sent by *anyone* will be collected by the collector, including messages sent by the bot itself. Since your bot sends a new message whenever a message is collected, this results in an infinite loop of spam.

Try changing it to this:

```
const filter = m => m.author.id == message.author.id;
```

This will ensure that the collector only collects messages sent by the user that used the command.

Alternatively, if you want to record the messages of everyone that sends a message (except your bot), try changing it to this:

```
const filter = m => m.author.id != message.client.user.id;
```

This will solve at least the spam portion of your problem.

The other problem simply appears to be an incorrect placement of your `else` statement. If you look at your second example, the `else` should come after `if (message.channel.id === channelID)`, but instead comes after the initial `if` statement `if (message.content === 'grimm!record')`.